# Correct method of authorizing scopes against Web Api and Mvc .NET 4 Applications

Tags: oauth, asp.net-web-api2, owin, identityserver4, owin-middleware

I'm using identity server 4 as an authentication server, and have successfully demonstrated authenticating clients for access to my MVC web application and my Web API application, both running on IIS under .NET 4.7.

The problem I'm having is finding the correct approach for ensuring clients are only able to access the endpoints they should after the authentication process. EG, I have two clients, one with a write scope, and one without. How do I ensure the one without is only able to access endpoints that will read my data and not amend it?

The best method I've found so far is to use an authorization attribute like this:
https://github.com/IdentityModel/Thinktecture.IdentityModel/blob/master/source/WebApi/ScopeAuthorizeAttribute.cs

However, this is marked as obsolete and I'm unaware of the version based on OWIN middleware is mentions. Considering my MVC and Web Api applications are unable to be updated to .NET core applications, what would be the best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the scope claims are available within the ASP.Net pipeline you can implement your own access control filter quite easily. It may be that that particular library is obsolete but the practice of enforcing scope in an MVC/WebAPI filter is certainly entirely valid.

Comment: Thanks - I assumed based on the obsolete comment about using the middleware version instead, there was a better way to achieve this now. In that case, I guess doing something similar to what's shown in the link is totally correct still.